# Unity3D Slider onValueChanged sending only 0 (or other defined value)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui, unity3d-editor

I'm trying to attach an onValueChanged event to my GUI Slider, but for some reason it gives me a mandatory option to put a value in (it's the fourth box in the "On Value Change (Single)" section). Then it only sends the forementioned value, not the actual value of the slider.

[image]

The code for the event is as follows:

```
public void ChangeWindDirection(float value)
{
    Debug.Log("New wind direction: " + value);
}
```

I tried restarting both Unity and Visual Studio 2013 to no avail. Now it even puts the box with a value to every new event I try to create.

Comment: There's a way to do this using UnityEvents, but I can't find an example...

Comment: Thanks for this question, I don't think one could come up with a more obfuscated way to enable this ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this

```
public void ChangeWindDirection(Slider slider)
{
    Debug.Log("New wind direction: " + slider.value);
}
```

Then assign the slider:
[image]

That way you can get the slider value, or other things the slider has :-)
Hope that's what you wanted :-)

Comment: Thanks, that works! :) But how is it possible that it works fine with the other sliders I have in the scene? All of my event handlers are the same (for now), but this was the only one that showed the fourth box.

Comment: Are you sure you selected the right one below Dynamic float http://imgur.com/5325W7m

Comment: I don't know what to say. That was the exact problem. Thank you very much, Jesper!

Comment: This is the first time I'm trying to do something in Unity on my own... :)

Comment: This works, but it's a bit quirky. If you just want the value (usually) then @dev_ter's answer is more straightforward: simply accept a float value (like in the OP) but make sure you select your function from the "Dynamic float" section (and then there will be no numeric field in the inspector).

Answer (score 41):

this is the best answer i found:

(posted as a comment by  Jesper)

Make sure you selected Dynamic float from the OnValueChanged drop down list in the inspector

[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFu5q.jpg)

Comment: This was the answer that helped me.

Comment: This is actually the best answer. Thank you!

Comment: This option does not appear to me

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Your method needs to take one *float* parameter in order for this option to appear on the pop up menu as in the picture.

Comment: Thank you for this. I find the alternative of passing a reference to the slider quite silly, as you could simply store that reference at design time, I mean unless you're creating sliders on the go, whose references you could keep too on the fly anyways.

This makes sense. Passing a simple value like this makes more sense to me, even if I have to cast to int later on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a "dynamic variable" from Unity's UI system (i.e. `ScrollRect`'s `scrollPosition` variable or a `Slider`'s value), simply create a method or property in the target script that matches the value type.

For example, `ScrollRect` can send a `Vector2` "dynamically" to a target script, so on the target script, you want to write a method that looks like this:

```
public [any return type] MyMethod(Vector2 myDynamicVar) {}
```

Or a property that looks like this:

```
public Vector2 myDynamicVar {set; [optional get;]}
```

This has a few vague but important implications:

1. the method and property written above won't appear as "dynamic" in other UI component's event callback lists if that UI component's "dynamic variable type" doesn't match (in this case `Vector2` for `ScrollRect`).
2. The method's signature needs to be JUST the dynamic variable type. i.e.: `public void MyMethod(Vector2 myDynamicVar, bool isCantBeHere) {}` won't appear as "dynamic" in the component's event callback list.

I hope I didn't leave anything out, this stuff isn't well documented (or easy to find). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, old sliders were bound just fine but new sliders showed the placeholder where you put a value. Even previous sliders, if I touch them and change it to the exact same method they were now showing the value placeholder and always sending zero. I had added a slider just an hour ago just fine, but now any change to the slider OnChanged will show the placeholder value. I did add a static field to the target class in that time, not sure if that is the cause.